# React hide header component for some routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have 3 components, WelcomePage, RegisterPage, HeaderLogOut.

I want that when user is on RegisterPage to hide that HeaderLogOut component. In RegisterPage user can click to logo icon of the app and will be redirected to WelcomePage and it will have HeaderLogOut component, which can redirect user back to RegisterPage.

I have seen similar questions and articles that show how this is done. But my problem is that for example, when I am on WelcomePage and I click to login, RegisterPage page has the HeaderLogOut and only after I refresh the page it disappears. Same with WelcomePage, when I am on RegistrationPage and I click the logo of the app, it redirects me to WelcomePage, and I have no HeaderLogOut, only after refresh it appears. I have had multiple attempts but I do not understand why it does not render the components immediately without a hard refresh.

For routing I use `useHistory` from `react-router-dom` hook.

```
const history = useHistory();

onClick={() => {
  history.push("/welcome");
}}
```

What I have in App.js

```
return (
  <React.Fragment>
      {/* {history.location.pathname === "/register" ? null : currentUser ? (
        <HeaderLogIn />
      ) : (
        <HeaderLogOut />
      )} */}
      {location.pathname !== "/register" && !currentUser && <HeaderLogOut />}
      {location.pathname !== "/register" && currentUser && <HeaderLogIn />}
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/register" component={RegistrationPage} />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/welcome"
        render={() => (currentUser ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <WelcomePage />)}
      />
      ... other routes
    </Switch>
  </React.Fragment>
);

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  currentUser: selectCurrentUser,
});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setCurrentUser: (user) => dispatch(setCurrentUser(user)),
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

I play with my user reducer like this to test either a logged in user or not.

```
const user = {
  username: "bvcbvc",
  email: "fdfsdfs",
};

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  currentUser: null, // user, if logged in
};
```

Comment: I don't see how the `currentUser` prop is tied to any route transitions, but what is changing `currentUser` after you transition to new route and reload the page?

Comment: @DrewReese I am using redux-logger and I see that its value is ```null``` meaning user is not logged. I believe the problem might be that the components to not rerender after route transitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that the `App` component isn't rerendered so either the `location` or `currentUser` aren't re-evaluated.

A solution could be to render, conditionally, the header components on a generic route outside the `Switch` so the `Route` can pass updated `location` value for conditional testing.

```
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Route
      render={({ location }) =>
        location.pathname !== "/register" && currentUser ? (
          <HeaderLogIn />
        ) : (
          <HeaderLogOut />
        )
      }
    />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/register" component={RegistrationPage} />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/welcome"
        render={() => (currentUser ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <WelcomePage />)}
      />
      ... other routes
    </Switch>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```